# setColorFilter does not work after setting background via setBackgroundResource

Tags: android, imageview, tint

I crated a small app, which cycles through tinted images of an ImageView on clicks.

It works well with the image set in the layout file, but it does not work when setting the image from the code like below.

Any help appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView mPic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
        mPic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.msh);

        mPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random random=new Random();
                ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(192, random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)),Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                mPic.setColorFilter(cf);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The color filter is applied to the `ImageView` *content*, not its *background*. Use [ImageView#setImageResource(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) to set the content and color filter will be applied.

If you need to add the `ColoFilter` to `ImageView`'s background, you can try something like `mPic.getBackground().setColorFilter()` (assuming that `getBackground()` returns non-null value).

Comment: Ah, right. Any possibility to set a color filter on the background?